# React Sign in with Google not redirecting to Dashboard

Tags: reactjs

I have setup a private route on my React app. I get a redirect to the homepage when I login using email and password, but when I use sign in with Google, the modal pops up and after sign in, it stays on login and I have to manually remove /login to access my dashboard.

This is my private route code.

````
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return currentUser ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
      }}
    ></Route>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Have you try to log "currentUser"

Comment: Hi. Yes. This is the response:

```

    "currentUser": {
        "uid": "bXHqH7yUpaPAIooxQFrsZ7yaRY2",
        "displayName": "Kyle Dux",
```

Comment: How about your code related to the switch and router? Could you also paste it ?

Comment: `    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LogIn} />
        </Switch>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
`

Comment: How about add exact  in <Route path="/login">

Comment: I tried it still shows the login page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235571/discussion-between-kyle-mabaso-and-truejasonxiefans).

Answer (score 0):

please refer to https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow to double check your code. I do think something wrong since I can't see your full code.